# I am trying to send email using helper class but show the error

Tags: magento2, email, helper

Send email using helper class but getting below error

> TypeError: Magento\Email\Model\Template::setVars(): Argument #1
> ($vars) must be of type array, null given

My code is,

```
<?php
namespace Custom\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $escaper;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        Escaper $escaper,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->logger = $context->getLogger();
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        try {
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $sender = [
                'name' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('Test'),
                'email' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('example@example.com'),
            ];
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('content_update_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo('example@example.com')
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have searched about the issue you are facing. You can review this PR for further details.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24448

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one by adding below setTemplateOptions `->setTemplateVars([])`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code

```
<?php
namespace Custom\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $escaper;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        Escaper $escaper,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->logger = $context->getLogger();
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        try {
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $sender = [
                'name' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('Test'),
                'email' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('example@example.com'),
            ];
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('content_update_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars([])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo('example@example.com')
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```